# Scroll the sites list up when a selection is made in the iPad app

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, ios-app, ipad

When I add a bunch of sites to the sidebar in the iPad app, then tap on the bottom one, I can't see all the options right away. I have to scroll to see all of them. See example:

[image]

In this example, I've selected Programmers and I can't see all the options. It'd be really nice if the sidebar would scroll up automatically so I can see all the options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great idea – this was definitely an annoying behavior.

This will be fixed in the next update to the beta release (version 1.1.0.108).